# Singularity in matrix when inverting in Matlab

Tags: matrices, matlab, inverse

As data I get a matrix A but in my algorithm I need to work on its inverse. What I do is:

```
C = inv(A) + B;
```

Then in another line I update A. In the next cycles I also need (updated) A inverse, again for this algorithm. And so on. In the later cycles I get this:

```
Matrix is close to singular or badly scaled. Results may be inaccurate. RCOND = 1.425117e-019
```

or this:

```
Warning: Matrix is singular to working precision.
```

or this:

```
Warning: Matrix is singular, close to singular or badly scaled. Results may be inaccurate. RCOND = NaN.
```

Can you help me how to avoid such singularity? Matrix is squared always.

Comment: can you post what matlab says when you type det(A), size(A) and rank(A)?

Comment: It will be hard to help without knowing what exactly the initial matrix is and what you are doing in your updates.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, it's very rarely a good idea to compute the inverse of a matrix explicitly.  There are usually other ways to do it that are better.

Answer (score 2):

You'd get yelled at and downvoted if you tried to post this over at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab). ;-)

The problem might be with you use of the function [`inv`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inv.html), which has a [spotty reputation](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/05/16/purpose-of-inv/) in Matlab circles. Try this:

```
C = A\eye(size(A)) + B;
```

Do you still get warnings? The trick is that here I used the backslash operator `\`, [`mldivide`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html), left matrix divide. This solves for the inverse of `A` by much more numerically stable, and often much faster methods. If you still had warnings you should check the `rank` of `A` and read up on [solving systems of linear equations](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/systems-of-linear-equations.html) and [`pinv`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pinv.html) as @pm89 suggested.

Answer (score 1):

It definitely depends on what you are doing and what matrix `A` represents (in some cases there might be programming error causing `A` become singular). But if the singularity of `A` is unavoidable, you can use the [**Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse) as an alternative to inverse matrix which has most of the properties of an inverse matrix ([See it in wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse)).

The equivalent command in *Matlab* would be [`pinv`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pinv.html).